# How to sync my mysql data with vuejs in my EDIT and ADD page

Tags: javascript, mysql, vue.js

Greetings all and pardon my novice for I am a mere beginner, I am trying to connect to mysql to add/edit data to my website, but I am very unsure on how to do so. If any advice could be spared it would be greatly appreciated.

Here is my code that pertains to this

ADD ENTRY PAGE

```
<div class="col-5">
    <label for="reason">Reason</label>
    <input
      type="text"
      class="form-control"
      value=""
      placeholder=""
      name="reason"
    />
  </div>
  <div class="col-12 d-grid">
    <button class="btn btn-primary" type="submit">Submit</button>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  computed: {
    id() {
      return this.$route.params.id;
    },

    serviceEntry() {
      let tmpEntry = null;

      for (let element of this.$store.state.serviceEntries) {
        if (element.id == this.id) {
          tmpEntry = element;
          break;
        }
      }
      return tmpEntry;
    },
  },
};
</script>


   EDIT ENTRY PAGE

 <div class="col-5">
    <label for="reason">Reason</label>
    <input
      type="text"
      class="form-control"
      value=""
      placeholder=""
      name="reason"
    />
  </div>
  <div class="col-12 d-grid">
    <button class="btn btn-primary" type="submit">Submit</button>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  computed: {
    id() {
      return this.$route.params.id;
    },

    serviceEntry() {
      let tmpEntry = null;

      for (let element of this.$store.state.serviceEntries) {
        if (element.id == this.id) {
          tmpEntry = element;
          break;
        }
      }
      return tmpEntry;
    },
  },
};
</script>
```

MODIFY ENTRY WITH A DELETE BUTTON

```
<template>
  <table class="table table-striped">
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <th scope="col">ID</th>
        <th scope="col">Location</th>
        <th scope="col">End User</th>
        <th scope="col">Order Number</th>
        <th scope="col">Date</th>
        <th scope="col">Application</th>
        <th scope="col">Service Tech</th>
        <th scope="col">Department</th>
        <th scope="col">Hours</th>
        <th scope="col">Travel Hours</th>
        <th scope="col">Contact Name</th>
        <th scope="col">Reason</th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
      <tr>
        <th scope="row">{{ serviceEntry.id }}</th>
        <td>{{ serviceEntry.location }}</td>
        <td>{{ serviceEntry.end_user }}</td>
        <td>{{ serviceEntry.order_number }}</td>
        <td>{{ serviceEntry.date }}</td>
        <td>{{ serviceEntry.application }}</td>
        <td>{{ serviceEntry.service_tech }}</td>
        <td>{{ serviceEntry.department }}</td>
        <td>{{ serviceEntry.hours }}</td>
        <td>{{ serviceEntry.travel_hours }}</td>
        <td>{{ serviceEntry.contact_name }}</td>
        <td>{{ serviceEntry.reason }}</td>
        <a
          href="/edit/{{this.id}}"
          type="button"
          onclick="event.stopPropagation();"
          class="btn btn-light btn-small"
          ><i class="bi bi-pencil"></i> Edit</a
        >
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  computed: {
    id() {
      return this.$route.params.id;
    },

    serviceEntry() {
      let tmpEntry = null;

      for (let element of this.$store.state.serviceEntries) {
        if (element.id == this.id) {
          tmpEntry = element;
          break;
        }
      }
      return tmpEntry;
    },
  },
};
</script>

     MAIN.JS 


import { createApp } from "vue";
import App from "./App.vue";
import "./registerServiceWorker";
import router from "./router";
import store from "./store";

createApp(App).use(store).use(router).mount("#app");
```

SOME OF THE INDEX

```
 async fetchServiceList({ commit }) {
      return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        axios({
          method: "get",
          url: prefix + "/api/service",
          headers: { "Content-Type": "application/json" },
        })
          .then(function (response) {
            console.log("Service List:");
            console.log(response);
            commit("setServiceEntries", response.data);
            resolve(true);
          })
          .catch(function (response) {
            //handle error
            console.log(response);
            reject(false);
          });
      });
    },
    // eslint-disable-next-line
    async createServiceEntry({ state }, payload) {
      return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        axios({
          method: "post",
          url: prefix + "/api/service/",
          data: {
            location: payload[0],
            user: payload[1],
          },
          headers: { "Content-Type": "application/json" },
        })
          .then(function (response) {
            //handle success
            console.log(response);
            resolve(response.data);
          })
          .catch(function (response) {
            //handle error
            console.log(response);
            reject();
          });
      });
    },

    async deleteServiceEntry() {
      return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        axios({
          method: "delete",
          url: prefix + "/api/service/delete/",
          headers: { "Content-Type": "application/json" },
        })
          .then(function (response) {
            //handle success
            console.log(response);
            resolve(true);
          })
          .catch(function (response) {
            //handle error
            console.log(response);
            reject(false);
          });
      });
    },
  },
});
```

I CAN PROVIDE MORE CODE IF NEED BE, BUT IT WILL BE TOMORROW MORNING. THANK YOU SO MUCH

Comment: don't understand it completely ... you have a function "createServiceEntry" but you don't use it, in add entry page you have an input that has no binding to a variable that could be sent to the server for storing. also in add entry you have "serviceEntry" as aread-only-computed, but for what?

Comment: Good observation. Those were set aside for  me from a coworker to possibly implement the add and edit entry page/button? The thing is, I am so new to coding that I am not sure where to go from here.